# how to setup react router properly v3?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup react-router for a react project of mine but for some reason cannot set up paths properly.In the router setup,component for IndexRoute works fine but when i try to access signup page,i get the error "Cannot GET /singup".Any hint at where i'am making a mistake?

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.4"
  }
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import Greetings from './components/Greetings';
import SignupPage from './components/signup/SignupPage';

export default(

    <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={Greetings} />
        <Route path="signup" component={SignupPage} />
    </Route>

)
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar'


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <NavigationBar />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

SignupPage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SignupPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>hey iam sign up page</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignupPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping Router component like this

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={Greetings} />
        <Route path="signup" component={SignupPage} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Tried the suggestion,but for some reason it's not working......I tried debugging using react Dev tools,while IndexRoute is being passed as props,Signup route is not visible

Comment: Do you have the whole project on github? If so, share the link

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys,it was error while serving up files form node.js

Here i was setting path only for '/', so when i sent a request for '/signup',i was getting the error 'cannot Get/signup' as there was no request mapping for the same

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
        // send file as response
        // __dirname -- > points to current director
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
    })
```

Inorder to solve it,I had to setup request mapping for any request url

```
app.get('/*',(req,res) => {
    // send file as response
    // __dirname -- > points to current director
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
})
```